# How to return Date value

Tags: php

Consider this simple code:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2015-12-12 23-23', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
```

Now I want to display the date in Europe/London time zone I've just applied but without giving any date format. I want the date format to be the same as input date. 
This: `$datetime->format()` doesn't work. Cannot find other method than `format()` to get this date :/

Comment: `echo $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: I've said that I don't want to give the date format , I just need it to be the same like input date.

Answer (score -2):

you can simply use `date` not `DateTime`

`<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('Y-m-d H-i');`

Comment: i don't want to change the default time zone